# How to conciliate REST and JSONschema?

Tags: python, rest, extjs, pyramid, jsonschema

I'm starting a new project that consists in an Extjs 6 application with a pyramid/python backend.

Due to this architecture, the backend will only provide an RPC and won't serve any page directly. My implementation of such a thing is usually based on REST and will fit nicely this CRUD application.

Regarding data validation i would like to move from Colander/Peppercorn that i always found awkward to the simpler and more streamlined jsonschema.

The idea here would be to move all the parameters - minus the id contained in the url when is the case - of the various requests into a json body that could be easily handled by jsonschema.

The main problem here is that GET requests shouldn't have a body and i definitely want to put parameters in there (filters, pagination, etc).

There's probably some approach to REST or REST-like and JSONschema but i'm not able to find anything on the web.

Edit: someone mentioned the question about body in GET HTTP request. While putting a body in a GET HTTP request is somehow possible, it's in violation of part of HTTP 1.1 specification and therefore this is NOT the solution to this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP GET with request body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

Comment: No it isn't. You CAN get a body in a HTTP GET request. It will work in some cases, but it's not what i want to do because it seems a bad hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use JSON Schema for input validation, but you are struggling to figure out how to validate query parameters with JSON Schema in a RESTful way.

Unfortunately, there isn't a definitive answer.  JSON Schema just wasn't designed for that.  Here are the options I have considered in my own work with REST and JSON Schema.

1. Convert query parameters to JSON then validate against the schema
2. Stuff your JSON into a query param and validate the value of that param.  (i.e.  /foo/1?params={"page": 2, "perPage": 10})
3. Use POST instead of GET and stick your fingers in your ears when people tell you you are doing REST wrong.  What do they know anyway.

I prefer option 1 because it is idiomatic HTTP.

Option 2 is probably the easiest to work with on the back-end, but it's dirty.

Option 3 is mostly a joke, but in all seriousness, there is nothing in REST or HTTP that says a POST can only be used for creation.  In fact, it is the most flexible and versatile of the HTTP methods.  Think of it like a factory that does something.  That something could generate and store a new resource or just return it.  If you are finding that you need to send a large number of query parameters, it's probably not really a simple GET.  My rule of thumb is that if the result is inherently not cacheable, it's possible that a POST is more appropriate (or at least not inappropriate).

Comment: Yes, i agree with your analysis. Still we are far from a proper solution. We would like to have a full jsonic api in a RESTful form, but the two thing doesn't concile, at least not perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need to do anything specific. In Pylons [`request.GET`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html) returns a dictionary (actually a MultiDict, but basically the same thing) of the parameters in the querystring. You can easily convert this to JSON or pass it directly to the schema validation.

Comment: A NestedMultiDict is not "basically the same thing" as a dict. It can have multiple values for the same key and you can easily see how this cannot be:
A) directly converted into a dict B) directly validated as a JSON file

Comment: Sorry, I don't see that at all. A MultiDict has a method [`dict_of_lists`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/interfaces.html#pyramid.interfaces.IMultiDict.dict_of_lists) which returns a dict where each key is a list; that's perfectly valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest would be to put the JSON string in a single query parameter.  If you have a JSON Schema to validate it, the client could use the same JSON Schema, and would therefor already have the data in JSON form.

`http://example.net/some/model/1?query={"foo":1,"bar":["baz","qux"]}`

If you for some reason dislike having JSON in the query, you could use a standard for converting query parameters.  [There is no universally agreed-upon specification for param strings](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/), but there are a few practices, depending on language and framework/library.

Example: `http://example.net/some/model/1?foo=1,bar[]=baz,bar[]=qux`

That might look cleaner to a new user, but will be more difficult if the client uses a lib/language that would querify JSON differently.